# Relativity and direction vectors

Tags: special-relativity, vectors

Imagine two massless observers, $ {\large O_y } $ and $ {\large O_x } $  , in an otherwise empty universe, with their feet at the origin and their heads at the arrow-heads of the unit $ \vec{y} $ and $ \vec{x} $ unit vectors respectively, with $ {\large O_y } $  looking out toward you from the $xy $ plane and ${\large O_x } $ lying on its right arm with its back to you and looking away from you into the $xy$ plane.

In this configuration, both observers are pointing to each other's left, so let's say that their common tail-point is in its 'left' state.

Now rotate $ {\large O_y } $  in the $xy$ plane so that it is pointing along $(-y)$ but still facing you. In this configuration, both observers are now pointing to each other's right and their common tail-point is in its 'right' state.

Now rotate $ {\large O_y } $  back to its original orientation and repeat the process ad infinitum.

From the frame in which $ {\large O_x } $ has a stable value, it appears that $ {\large O_y } $  has no stable value and yet from the point of view of $ {\large O_y } $ ,
( which always points from $ {\large O_y } $ 's feet to $ {\large O_y } $ 's head ),  since $ {\large O_x } $ points alternately to $ {\large O_y } $ 's left and $ {\large O_y } $ 's right, it seems to be $ {\large O_x } $ that has no stable value .

Each is stable with respect to itself and keeps changing from the point of view of the other.

In an otherwise empty universe, which one of $ {\large O_x } $ or $ {\large O_y } $  is correct in its claim to be the stable one?

Answer (score 0):

> In an otherwise empty universe, which one of Ox or Oy is correct in its claim to be the stable one?

The one whose gyroscope remains stable. The presence or absence of the other observer is irrelevant, only their own gyroscope measurements are relevant.

Comment: Yes Dale, I thought of that after I posted the question, but the 'rotation' of $ {\large O_y } $ is not what I meant, I meant a 'replacement' of $ {\large O_y } $. There is no gyroscopic forces involved, and the observers are massless. I have ammended the question accordingly.

Comment: @pete it is against the forum policy to change a question after it has received a valid answer in a way that invalidates the answer. I have reverted the edits. The idea of magically replacing one observer with another is non-physical anyway, so the revised version would likely have been closed. Your original question is better

Comment: '@dale' Oh ok. re. question-change policy. But still, The question was posted to get to get opinions on an idea,  do you really think  the revised version would have been closed? why? The idea of an observer being 'massless' is equally non-physical yet textbook derivations of the relativistic transformations between different inertial frames make no reference to the 'masses' of those observers either. How can you accept the notion of a 'massless observer' yet balk at 'magically replacing' such observers?

Comment: @pete since the observers are not moving at c they are necessarily massive. The correct terminology would be “negligible mass” or “in the limit as the mass approaches 0”. I just don’t bother to make an issue of it since the correct terminology is well known. But I know of no such limit or approximation for your modified scenario

Comment: '@ Dale' Still though, couldn't you just treat it as a 'what if' scenario. As I intended the question, which of Ox or Oy do would $\textbf {you yourself} $ say is correct in their claim to be the stable one?

Comment: @pete you seem to miss the problem. “What if” scenarios that can be analyzed by the known laws of physics are fine. But the modified scenario cannot. Since we cannot use the laws of physics then it will just be opinion or magic, neither of which belongs on this site. There is no way to make your scenario, not even in the sense of some idealized limit. So it simply cannot be analyzed by physics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142722/discussion-between-pete-and-dale).

Comment: '@ Dale' Yes, I've move the discussion to chat.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as clarified by your comments on Dale's answer, appears to boil down to this 'If we disregard everything that might allow us to determine in an objective sense which of the two axes is the more stable, is it possible for us to determine in an objective sense which of the two axes is more stable?' the answer to which should be obvious.

Comment: If two inertial frames are moving with respect to each other, is there any 'objective' sense in which one of them can be said to be 'stationary' and the other not? can't both claim with equal validity to be the 'stationary' one? since velocity is relative. Doesn't a similar thing apply to my scenario?